# Upload Image File along with regular Form Data

Tags: django, image, vue.js

I am using django with VueJS. The data is updating properly in my database.

I need to **accomplish two things**:

1. Post the correct content to the field **image_file**.
2. Get the downloaded **image file** pasted onto the servers folder which is **media/shop/images**

My attempted code is as below:

**models.py**

```
...
image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
...
urlpatterns += [
   url(r'^Post-Items-Axios$', myviews.Post_Items_Axios, name='Post-Items-Axios'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def Post_Items_Axios(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_itemfullhd = request.data['Item Name']
        data_image_file = request.data['Item Image File']

        td_items, created = Md_Items.objects.get_or_create(
            itemfullhd = data_itemfullhd)

        td_items.imagefl = data_imagefl
        td_items.image_file = data_image_file
        td_items.save()

    data = { 'data_itemfullhd': data_itemfullhd }
    return Response(data)
```

**bm_home.html**

```
<template id="product-edit">
    <div>
    <h2>Product details</h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edit-name">Item Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="edit-name" v-model="product.itemfullhd" required/>
        </div>

        <!-- Upload single Image files -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edit-imagefile">Image</label>
            <input type="file" id="edit-imagefile" @change="onFileChanged" required/>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="updateProduct">Save</button>
        <a class="btn btn-dark"><router-link to="/product-list">Cancel</router-link></a>
    </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Vue template**

```
var ProductEdit = Vue.extend({
    template: '#product-edit',
    data: function () {
        return {
            product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id),
            selectedImage: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onFileChanged (event) {
            this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0]
            this.product.image_file = this.selectedImage.name
        },
        updateProduct: function () {
            let product = this.product;
            products[findProductKey(product.id)] = {
                id: product.id,
                itemfullhd: product.itemfullhd,
                image_file: product.image_file,
            };
            const data = {
                "Item Name": product.itemfullhd,
                "Item Image File": product.image_file,
            }
            // const formData = new FormData()
            // formData.append('image_file', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name)
            // axios.post('/biggmount_home/Post-Items-Axios', formData, data)

            axios.post('/biggmount_home/Post-Items-Axios', data)
            router.push('/product-list');
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: So? What's your question? What's the problem you're facing with your current code? an error? unexpected behavior?

Comment: My problem is how to pass this.selectedImage to django view so that I may use request.FILES in the view OR maybe any other option.

Comment: request.data['Item Image File'] is empty? I understand what you want, but you should specify your problem. What about your current code is not working? What do see in `request.POST`? You can't just expect us to read your code and find issues. That's not even how I debug my own code. I use a debugger and my browser debug tools and check what is actually being posted, so I can see where the problem is. Is it the js code? Is the view code?

Comment: You say "The data is updating properly in my database" so what's the issue?

Comment: I need to send both the values to the backend [const data] & const formData.
Right now I am able to send any one and achieve partial success.
const data = {
                "Item Name": product.itemfullhd,
                "Item Image File": product.image_file,
            }
// const formData = new FormData()
// formData.append('image_file', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS upload image with additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894691/vuejs-upload-image-with-additional-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes below have given me the result that I was looking to achieve:

**Vue template**

```
var ProductEdit = Vue.extend({
    template: '#product-edit',
    data: function () {
        return {
            product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id),
            selectedImage: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onFileChanged (event) {
            this.selectedImage = event.target.files[0]
        },
        updateProduct: function () {
            let product = this.product;
            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('Item Image', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name)
            formData.append('Item Name', product.itemfullhd)
            axios.post('/biggmount_home/Post-Items-Axios', formData)
            router.push('/product-list');
        },
    }
});
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def Post_Items_Axios(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_itemfullhd = request.data['Item Name']
        td_items, created = Md_Items.objects.get_or_create(
            itemfullhd = request.data['Item Name'],
            )
        td_items.image_file = request.data['Item Image']

        td_items.save()
    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```